# Volume and other indicators disappeared in the classic desktop

Tags: gnome-classic

I updgraded my ubuntu to 12.04 LTS and then installed gnome classic since I do not like unity. But then the volume icon at the up-right corner has disappeared. How can I get it back to that place. Thanks for any help.

[image]

Comment: It is the first time I see a message, like the one below, saying that this question is "protected by the community"! Wow! Therefore, I would like to take the opportunity to ask what does that mean? What does the protection consists in?, and why are not all questions protected?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

from your screenshot, it looks like you have removed the `indicator applet complete` applet

[image]

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+ right click the panel to add the applet.  You can similarly remove the other gnome-applets.

If the applet doesnt appear in your list, install the applet from software-center:

[image: Install via the software center]

or via the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-applet-complete
```

Comment: ALT+Win+Right Click? Why did they change this from a simple right click or made it something easy like CTRL+Right Click. I was under the impression that "Add to Panel" was gone for good.

Comment: Its a combination of upstream changes from the gnome-devs and compiz changes I believe.

Comment: Sorry but this is a bad advice. While it has everything, it doesn't work with another panel applets (for example notification area applet).

Comment: @VJovic - the ubuntu indicator applet (from 11.10 I think) effectively replaced the notification applet.  If you have an app that requires the old notification applet, you need to use the white-list capability of the indicator applet.

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem too. 
Run **gnome-sound-applet** from the command line to check that it is installed and working.

To start the sound applet automatically, go to 
**System Tools>Preferences>Startup Applications** 
and add Command 
**gnome-sound-applet**

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-applet-complete

sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

than refer to the following figure to make visible the applets that you need. [image]

Answer (score 2):

Alt+Win+ right click the panel to add an applet.

There are two kinds of indicator applets. 
I dont know the exact translation, but there is a standard and a full version.
Try the full version.

Comment: I did checked on that but I think I have only one indicator applet which says "Indicator applet complete".

Comment: You got to be kidding me. I just alt+win+right clicked the panel and added indicator and it's working ! you sir, have one beer from me

Answer (score 1):

yes, same problem, 
maybe: http://code.google.com/p/volti/

Comment: So the solution is.. ?

Comment: First I installed volti, but now using gnome-sound-applet.