# Volume icon from top panel has disappeared after upgrading

Tags: 12.04, gnome-classic, volume-control

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Volume icon disappeared in the classic desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126411/volume-icon-disappeared-in-the-classic-desktop)

I have upgraded my system to 12.04 but the problem is 
after upgrading the volume icon from the top panel has been disappeared(in Ubuntu classic).

I tried some of solution like "**Indicator applet complete**"

But this brings the whole bunch of stuff like "date and time" and "my name" which I already have.

So is there any other way I can bring only that volume icon back.