# Volume icon disappeared in the classic desktop. Again

Tags: gnome-classic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Volume icon from top panel has disappeared after upgrading](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126895/volume-icon-from-top-panel-has-disappeared-after-upgrading)

I have the same problem as was described in [Volume and other indicators disappeared in the classic desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126411/volume-icon-disappeared-in-the-classic-desktop)
But the answer for that topic provides non equivalent result. Take a look at the upper right corner of the original image from the previous topic. There is a SINGLE icon for account, online status, and system management. The "indicator applet complete" provides a separate icon for each action. This is not the same bar that I had in 11.10 and lost in 12.04.