# How to restore unity after gnome-shell installation?

Tags: 12.04, unity, gnome, panel

I Just installed `gnome-shell` in my 12.04 box and, unity disappears from the login screen.

This is what I've done trying to fix:

1. #Exec: unity --reset`
2. **Purge and install: indicator-session**
3. **Set Display full username to true in gsettings**

`

Comment: is it related to this?
http://askubuntu.com/questions/126411/volume-and-other-indicators-disappeared-in-the-classic-desktop

Comment: I tried "sudo apt-get install indicator-applet-complete" yesterday. By the way, sound applet is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-Installed ubuntu, the name is missing just because I disable guest-account.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

If you have compizConfig Setting Manager installed then try

```
ccsm
```

Comment: Let me try that....

Comment: Let me know if it works.

Comment: Didnt work, I've exec that command and reboot, username still missing so do the icon of user.

Comment: Do I have to exec: "ccsm" after "sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop" ?

Comment: No, just try that to see if there is any conflicts, and try to resolve them.

Comment: I'll check ASAI arraived home.

Comment: Where can I see conflicts? on terminal?  CLI doesnt print nothing about conflicts...

Comment: Oh, sorry, yes you have to run ccsm.

Comment: Nothing.... :S.... X-( No queria reinstalar ubuntu otravez..... I dont want to reinstall....

Answer (score 2):

If you were using `compizconfig-settings-manager` and messed up your desktop. Only thing that worked successfully for me, was repair it with the same program..

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>  (To open **terminal**)
2. `ccsm` (To start program.)
3. Repair what you have messed up.

All other stuff what you can find online, such as

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

haven't give any result. It was just waste of time.

Answer (score 2):

Just open **CCSM**, scroll down to **Desktop**, click on **Ubuntu Unity Plugin**, make sure **Enable Unity Plugin** is *checked* in the box on the left side panel of the CCSM window.

[image]

That fixed mine. No reboot required.

Comment: There is no such check box in CCSM in 12.04.

Comment: Yes, there is. See screen-shot.