# Going back to Unity 15

Tags: unity, 15.04

The thing is that first I was in unity then I moved to gnome and then to KDE.
Know I moved back to unity but I can't see anything , just the wall paper. I'm unable to see the dock. But I can access to the terminal. How do I fully restore unity?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

also refer:

[How to restore unity after gnome-shell installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146754/how-to-restore-unity-after-gnome-shell-installation)

Comment: Didn't worked. When I restart the laptop I still see the Kubuntu image. So I think first I need to get rid of Kubuntu .

Comment: I have the unity desktop but when I restart I still see the Kubuntu logo